# Does the Microsoft Sculpt keyboard or other Microsoft ergonomic keyboards work on ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, compatibility

I have been thinking of buying an ergo keyboard for coding and stuff. But confused if microsoft keyboards would work.

Comment: Keyboards work fine, the problem are mice. If you want to use a Microsoft mouse you'll probably have to install resetmsmice to get it working properly, you can find it on github (you have to build it from source though).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never had a problem getting and USB or PS2 keyboard or mouse working under Ubuntu. I was under the impression that [resetmsmice](https://launchpad.net/resetmsmice) was only needed for certain wireless versions and even then only if you were dual booting windows. @dsSTORM

Answer (score 8):

I'm typing this from a sculpt split keyboard.  It has worked well for the last 1.5 years or so that i've had it.  Recently, my update to 18.04 broke some of my specialty keys (snap window to left half of screen, etc), but other than that, it's been working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft sculpt ergonomic keyboard & Mouse with Ubuntu 20.04. They work as plug and play except for the Windows button on the mouse does not do anything.

Also, note that the keyboard does not have any LED to indicate Caps Lock.